# Appearing/disappearing UITabbar with navigation

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

I have a `UITabBar` with four tabs. My second tab has two child navigation controller like 2nd tab -> child VC1 -> child VC2.

Now when I go to child VC1, i want to disappear/hide the bottom tabbar & if I go to child VC2 from VC1, the bottom tabbar should be shown again.

If I back from VC2 to VC1, the tabbar will be disappear and then again back from VC1 to 2nd tab controller, the tabbar should be appear again.

How can I achieve this thing ?

In the storyboard, I selected "Hide Bottom Bar on Push" for the child VC1, the tabbar is disappear on this controller but the problem is when I go to child VC2 from VC1, the tabbar still disappear.

How can solve this issue ? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In VC1

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    self.tabBarController.tabBar.hidden = YES;
}
```

In VC2

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    self.tabBarController.tabBar.hidden = NO;
}
```

Comment: did you remove Hide Bottom Bar on Push? just use the code. It works for me.

Comment: Yes, i removed. But the problem is still exist.

Comment: I removed navigation controller from both VC1 and VC2 and the bottom bar is appearing and disappearing as expected, but the problem is now the navigation bar is disappear in VC2

Comment: I hope you are using this hierarchy TabController -> NavigationController -> VC1 and use only one navigation controller.

Comment: Yaa, Currently I have Tabcontroller->NavigationCOntroller->Tab Controller->VC1->VC2. Between tab controller and VC1 and VC2, there is no navigation controller. In this case, my bottom tabbar is now working perfectly as i expected throughout the navigation, but now the problem exist in navigation bar. There is no navigation bar on VC2.

Comment: If i insert a navigational controller between VC1 and VC2 like Tabcontroller->NavigationController->Tab Controller->VC1->NavigationController->VC2 , the navigation bar appear on the VC2, but the tabbar disappear aggain on that.

Comment: which is your parent controller on tab? if its VC1, then you should embed VC1 to navigation controller and embed that to tabbarcontroller. TabController -> NavigationController -> VC1. I don't get this Tabcontroller->NavigationCOntroller->Tab Controller->VC1 what is the TabController after navigationController?

Comment: Oh my mistake, "Tab Controller" is parent controller that is embeded with navigation controller like Tabcontroller->NavigationController->Tab controller (VC0)->VC1->NavigationController->VC2, here "Tab Controller" should be mentioned as a view controller that is tab's root/parent controller

Comment: This should be the hierarchy Tabcontroller->NavigationController->VC0->VC1->VC2. Add this 'self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isHidden = false' to your VC2 if you are hiding navigation bar in any controller.

Comment: Thanks i solved it, it was my problem. I accidentally hide navigation bar in my code & forget to comment out that. Thanks a lot, it's the correct answer.